# timepicker ban entry in a field on a mobile phone

Tags: javascript, jquery

https://github.com/jonthornton/jquery-timepicker#methods I use this timer. in particular its property

```
'disableTextInput': true
```

and

```
'useSelect':true
```

Everything works fine on the computer, but you can enter anything you want into the field from your mobile phone. I tried to add such a property to the field

```
readonly: true
```

the list ceased to fall out with time for selection (although it worked for the date). Can anyone tell me how to fix it?

UPD

```
<div class="container" id="none1" style="display: block;"> 
      <input type="text" name="time_visit" class="timepicker ui-timepicker-input" required="" id="id_time_visit" autocomplete="off">
</div>
```

and js

```
$("#id_time_visit").timepicker({
       timeFormat: 'H:i',
       minTime: '8', 
       maxTime: '19',
       step: 60,
       disableTimeRanges: [],
       listWidth:1,
       disableTextInput: true,
       disableTouchKeyboard: true,
     });
     $('#id_time_visit').timepicker('option', 'disableTimeRanges', disRange);   
   });
```

Answer (score 1):

can you try

```
'disableTouchKeyboard': true;
```

Comment: update question. Time appears after selecting a date. I don’t think that it somehow affects, considering that it works on PC

Comment: not sure what happened, i think you should check https://github.com/jonthornton/jquery-timepicker/issues?q=is%3Aissue+mobile+is%3Aclosed or add new issue in Gihub

Answer (score 0):

the problem is resolved. Inattentively used `'disableTextInput': true` and '`useSelect':true` together. But disableTextInput option was removed in version 1.3.0 and replaced with the useSelect option. Part of the reason for removing it was that it was very difficult to fix all of the edge cases, like pasting. when left only `usedSelect` everything worked